# @{#if DEBUG} not working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, minify

My web.config file contains this

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
   <assemblies>
      // some assemblies
   </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml file I have

```
@{#if DEBUG}
  // include all css and js files
@{#else}
  // include the minified and combined versions of the css and js files
@{#endif}
```

Problem is that the @{#if DEBUG} branch gets executed.  If I change that branch to @{#if !DEBUG} then the else branch gets executed.  Why is this?

Thanks.

Sachin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web.config `debug=""` attribute does not affect preprocessor symbols.

You can check for that attribute directly like this:

```
var compilation = WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/compilation") as CompilationSection;
return compilation != null && compilation.Debug;
```

(You should put this in a static property in any class, then check that property in a normal `if` statement)

Comment: Where would I put this and then how do I call it in my _Layout.cshtml file?  What does @{#if DEBUG} check then?

Comment: `#if` checks against the defined preprocessor symbols.  I'm not actually sure where to define those.

Comment: Anywhere, but presumably in a static property.